# Custom url path for js, css and image files with 'gulp build'

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, yeoman

Since Yeoman no longer uses Grunt, I'm not sure how Gulp changes the URLs for the HTML/CSS/JS files through gulp build. I don't know what to add to the gulpfile.js to do this.

Basically, how can I have it so all my URLS change from this:

```
background-image:url('/images/example.jpg')
<img src="/images/example.jpg"/>
```

to this:

```
background-image:url('/examplefolder/examplefolder2/images/example.jpg')
<img src="/examplefolder/examplefolder2/images/example.jpg"/>
```

during the gulp-build process?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at gulp-replace-path plugin and similar ones.

Comment: Hi @Shilly will this allow me to swap all the src links at once instead of one at a time?

Comment: "Yeoman no longer uses Grunt"? The choice of build system in your Yeoman workflow is up to you

Comment: Are you looking for a way to change the markup, the actual locations of the referenced files, or both? (That is, are you successfully saving example.jpg to /examplefolder/examplefolder2/images/, and you just need to get the html to reflect that?)